# Java sorted Collection impl that allows many equal values

Tags: java, collections

I tried  to use TreeSet:

```
Comparator<Product> pc = (p1, p2) -> ((Double) p1.getPrice()).compareTo(p2.getPrice());
Set<Product> products = new TreeSet<>(pc);
products.add(new Product(10));
products.add(new Product(10));
```

but problem is that it can not contain more than one equal values in terms of Comparator, and so only one of the product will be in `products` set.

I need some Collection implementation, that will order newly inserted value, allow many equal(in terms of Comparator) values, and have insert complexity **log(n)** (possibly tree based impl)

Comment: Do your products have something unique, like a productId?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List implementation that maintains ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675446/list-implementation-that-maintains-ordering)

Comment: assyliad: no I dont need ID
It seems that Guava TreeMultiset is fine for me, but I wonder if I can do it just using Java Collection API.

Comment: When you say "tree-based", do you really mean *sorted*? The implementation of a collection internally shouldn't really matter to you.

Comment: You might find something interesting in [Why is there no SortedList in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8725387/3788176).

Comment: For a time complexity comparison for example see http://infotechgems.blogspot.de/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `class` in the JDK that matches your exact requirements is [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). From the documentation:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a `Comparator` provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

And

> Implementation note: this implementation provides `O(log(n))` time for the enqueuing and dequeuing methods (`offer`, `poll`, `remove()` and `add`); linear time for the `remove(Object)` and `contains(Object)` methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods (`peek`, `element`, and `size`).

---

You can also carry on using `TreeSet` but provide a `Comparator` that gives a unique answer. For example, if your `Product` has a unique `name`:

```
Comparator<Product> pc = Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice)
                         .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Product::getName));
```

Note the use of `Comparator.comparing` rather than your lambda - it's neater and more robust.

Comment: Thanks, 
I just have tried JDK PriorityOueue and it is fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case you really need to order the elements at insert time you can use Guava's [TreeMultiset](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html).

Answer (score 0):

So,
[PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) worked for me.

[TreeMultiset](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) did not. When I add two different objects:
`products.add(new Product(10));
products.add(new Product(10));`
it contains two links for first instance, and none for second()