# `add` and `addAll` from a `PriorityQueue` behave differently, why is this?

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

When transferring elements from a `PriorityQueue` to an `ArrayList` I noticed `List.add` and `List.addAll` behave differently. But I'm not sure why.

Example code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<String> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    heap.add("a");
    heap.add("aa");
    heap.add("aaa");

    ArrayList<String> listAddAll = new ArrayList<>();
    listAddAll.addAll(heap);
    System.out.println(listAddAll);

    ArrayList<String> listAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!heap.isEmpty()){
      listAdd.add(heap.remove());
    }
    System.out.println(listAdd);
  }
```

The `listAddAll` contains `[aaa, a, aa]` while `listAdd` contains `[aaa, aa, a]`. I'd expect both to be the latter as that is the order specified by the comparator.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, misread it.

Comment: You are not observing the difference between `add` and `addAll` but between [traversing the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2277430/2711488) and repeatedly calling `remove()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ArrayList.addAll` is implemented to use `Collection.toArray` like this:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

And `PriorityQueue.toArray` is just a copy operation of the underlying array:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(queue, size);
}
```

So, `addAll` will insert the queue elements according to their order in the `queue` field which is balanced binary heap that preserves the order of elements as a tree not a list. You're getting the raw array representing the tree not a sorted list.