# new LinkedList<>(...) can't guarantee collection data's order

Tags: java, collections

i'm use java 8
idk why this can't guarantee collection data's order

```java
PriorityQueue<Place> firstQue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.v));

//add data into firstQue`

Queue<Place> que = new LinkedList<>(firstQue);
```

```
firstQue = [1, 1, 2, 4];

que = [1, 2, 1, 4]; //what???
```

Comment: It's `PriorityQueue` that can't guarantee the order, unless you use `poll` to get its elements (which the `LinkedList` constructor does not).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`LinkedList#(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)):

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's **iterator** *[emphasis added]*.

From the documentation of [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The `Iterator` provided in method `iterator()` *[...]* are *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

<sup>**Note:** The documentation above is for Java 21, but the quoted behavior was/is the same in Java 8.</sup>

That explains how your linked list does not contain the elements from the priority queue in the order of the elements' priority. If you want to understand **why** the iterator of a priority queue is not guaranteed to traverse the elements in any particular order, see the following Stack Overflow Q&A: [The built-in iterator for java's PriorityQueue does not traverse the data structure in any particular order. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2277430/6395627)